# Prove that set in Axiom of Pairing is unique

Tags: set-theory

Here is the [Axiom of Pairing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Axiom_of_pairing) from the set theory

$$ \forall A\,\forall B \,\exists C \,\forall D \left[D \in C \Longleftrightarrow (D = A \vee D = B)\right] $$

I need to prove that the set $C$ is unique. So, on the contrary, I assume that its not unique. So, lets says, there are two such sets. $C_1$ and $C_2$. So, how do I proceed from there ?

Comment: Take an element from the first set, show it is in the second one and vice versa if needed.

Comment: Use the [axiom of extensionality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Axiom_of_extensionality). If $C$ and $C'$ both satisfy then it can be proved that they have the same elements.

Comment: So, let $z \in C_1 $ be arbitrary. How does it follow that $z \in C_2 $ ? Do I use axiom of pairing here ?

Comment: @user9026: $z\in C_1\leftrightarrow (z=A\lor z=B)\leftrightarrow z\in C_2$, so by extensionality $C_1=C_2$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose given $A$ and $B$. Suppose we have $C_1$ and $C_2$ s.t. $\forall D [D \in C_i \iff (D = A \lor D = B)]$. Then we will use extensionality to prove that $C_1 = C_2$.

Suppose we have $x \in C_1$. Then $x = A$ or $x = B$. In either case, we have $x \in C_2$. Then $C_1 \subseteq C_2$.

By the same argument, $C_2 \subseteq C_1$.

Then by the axiom of extensionality, $C_1 = C_2$.